# Java Using High Virt Memory

Tags: java, linux, apache

[image]

According to this I'm using 14GB+ on a java process in apache.
In am only running a Minecraft control panel and when I run a memory check via Minecraft it tells me I have using 7.6GB of 8GB. When I should be looking at around 1-2GB max of used space.

I'm new to linux and this is a little confusing to me. I believe this is an inaccuracy but if someone could explain what is going on here that would be appreciated?

Comment: I think this is more a question for serverfault or superuser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout linuxatemyram.com

Also if its a virtual machine Java useage may not be accurate.

You can limit memory to a certain size by launching with these params

```
-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m
```

To limit to 1gb for example

Comment: The website link was really helpful thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Its the user apache running a java process and yes it is using 14gigs.

I think you need to get your hands dirty and run a few commands.

But before I get there I should explain how JVM works - when a java process is launched as part of the start up configuration items are given called Xmx and Xms and this can be really range depending on what the application is and what it is doing. Why oh why so high then ?

Well Java Virtual Machine has something called Memory heaps - the larger it is set to the longer it will be before a full garbage collection is done - so on lets say high end Bank machines this be set to real high so it can go all day without requiring a restart (the restart is the full garabage collection) - The longer it is left to garbage collect the longer it will take to garbage collect so in essence a small app outage unless other take over during those periods.....

So do a

```
ps -elf |grep java 
or 
ps auwx|grep java
```

Look at its config and look out for Xmx and Xms values

Speak to who ever has configured it to find out why so high

Then do a

```
free -m
```

See how much actual free memory you have and if swap is being used, since if you end up in swap then the box will go slower due to it using disk as memory..

Hope by the end of this you are more Linux familiar

E2a

If it is set to 40gigs and it is available, be sure it will actually use up that 40gigs since as the name states its a virtual machine and it then handles its own resources for what it has been set.... so it will slowly slowly eat up the 40gigs or near enough before attempting a full GC... 
What you actually need is **jconsole** and a connection to that java pid or .. if accessible via remote jmx call..

jconsole should be part of default java install

E2A again if the reason you are looking at it is because there are performance issues then maybe you are using the wrong commands

```
sudo apt-get install nmon iftop
or
sudo yum install nmon iftop
```

run **nmon** press **cmd** amongst others you may wish to run

iftop if you wish to look at network throughput

Comment: Feel a little more educated here now thanks :)